# activity auto restart when i try to close android application

Tags: android, forceclose

i have three activities (A, B, C). This is my activity circle A => B, B => C, C => A
when start activity C from activity B complete i don't call finish() function on B activity. when start A activity from C activity complete i all finish() function on C Activity. In A activity i implement back button to close application by use this code:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

i want to close my app but the application restart B activity

Comment: you are not supposed to do that.

Comment: I agree, Android will close your application when resources need to be freed, no need for killing your app. This is a old habit coming from older operating system.

Answer (score 0):

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Wont kill all the activity. you must use CLEAR_TOP flags in your intent. or you must use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779571/how-to-finish-another-activity/15779714#15779714)
method to finish ur B activity from C activity if needed. Another thing is use  `finish()`
Inside the onrestart overide method in your B activity.

Answer (score 0):

when you start A from C just add FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to your intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```